# BIRT Java Driver - getDatabase noSuchMethod error

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven, mongo-java-driver

I'm using the mongodb-driver 3.5.0 with Eclipse, and I get no errors in the IDE but when I run my program I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDatabase(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase;

as an error. I've already checked and I'm only using 3.5.0 through a Maven dependency. For some reason everything before to get the MongoClient works fine, it's just `getDatabase` that isn't working.

EDIT: I did a rough rebuild of the project using a gradle dependency instead of Maven, and that solved the issue. I'll keep looking into it to find the cause.

Example code below:

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import com.mongodb.client.model.CreateCollectionOptions;
import com.mongodb.client.model.ValidationOptions;


        public static Document reportFind(String id, String destination) {

            ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.get();
            ObjectId provider_id = new ObjectId(id);
            String provider_string = provider_id.toString();
            String db = "loginapp";

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("loginapp");
            MongoCollection<Document> coll =            database.getCollection("reporttemplates");
            System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");
```

Comment: *but when I run my program I get Exception in thread "main"* how do you execute the program?

Comment: This is running it in the Eclipse IDE, I used a Maven dependency for the driver as well

Comment: you might want to check your IDE run configurations then, since the class shared with its imports looks fine for the `getDatabase` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the [mongodb's current documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/) the implementation of getDatabse is as:

```
public MongoDatabase getDatabase(String databaseName)
```

> Parameters:
>       databaseName - the name of the database to retrieve
>
> Returns:
>       a MongoDatabase representing the specified database
>
> Throws:
>       IllegalArgumentException - if databaseName is invalid

This seems completely fine according to your implementation as well. I would hence invest time in investigating the build process for the project of which above is part of.